# USE DATABASE command on SQL PLUS ORACLE 11gr1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

After successfully installing ORACLE 11gR1 on Windows7 32bit platform, I can go inside the SQL PLUS and I can also create database, but I still don't have any clue how to use database.

in MySQL the command to use database should be:

```
USE MYDATBASENAME;
```

In SQL SERVER also quite the same:

```
USE [DATABASE];
```

But I have no idea how to use database in ORACLE 11gR1 via SQLPLUS, any body have any ideas?

I'm planning to create a table after I succeed in using the `USE` command.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Even though they all use the same noun the term "database" is something completely different between MySQL (SQL Server) and Oracle.

Usually a MySQL database is mapped to a schema/user in Oracle. In Oracle there is a 1:1 relationship between schemas and users.

A "database" in Oracle refers to the complete installation (which is also named "instance"). As there is typically only a single instance/installation there is no sense in "switching a database" in Oracle.

The closest thing to "USE mydatabase" in Oracle would be to switch the current schema:

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = other_user;
```

Then you can access all tables of `other_user` without prefixing them. This of course requires your current user to have at least select privileges on the tables of the other user (i.e schema)

Comment: thank you, i've found it sqlplus MYUSERNAME/MYPASSWORD@MYHOSTNAME:1616

The 1 to 1 relationship really enlighten me :D thanks

Comment: You've typoed `SESSION` in your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

you can login into oracle using `sqlplusw username/password@connect-string` and then do a `select  * from v$database`

use `select instance_name from v$instance;` to find out which database are you currently connected to

Comment: thank you for the assistance sir, i've got the result from  SELECT name FROM v$DATABASE;
it shows me the database i've just created, now i'm having 2 databases there , how can i use one of them and create table on it,

Answer (score 1):

TNSNAMES.ora has the details about which database you are connecting to.

Comment: which is in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Comment: I suspect the man was referring to schemas, rather than databases per se.