# Oracle Database schema name

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i set the db name on my worksheet so i don't have to retype every time I write a query.

Here is one example.

```
SELECT db_t.employee FROM table1;
```

I am trying not to type db_t every time. Is there a way I can set a db name for a session.

Comment: Have you tried 'USE db_t'?

Comment: Duplicate of [USE DATABASE command on SQL PLUS ORACLE 11gr1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461861/use-database-command-on-sql-plus-oracle-11gr1)

Comment: You can also create a **public synonym** for the tables you want to access. `create public synonym employee for db_t.employee` Then you don't have to specify the schema every time. If you have multiple users who need access to the tables in `db_t`, this is a standard practice.

Comment: The problem is i am not the owner of the database so i can't create a synonym. Maybe i didn't explain it well. I am trying to minimize the schema name from my queries. I just want to set it once then write bunch of queries without calling the schema name each time.

Comment: @DanielMarcus this is Oracle, so there is no `use` command.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what a worksheet is, though (and `db_t` seems an odd name for a schema).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default schema for the session with:

```
alter session set current_schema = db_t;
```

Answer (score -2):

There is default database for a current session only.It can be set by-
USE ;

Ex: USE db_t;

Post above statemnet, the sqls can be run without schema name.

Comment: Downvoting because that fails with `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`.